# How do I resolve a null error in my custom user context?

Tags: reactjs

Here is my custom context:

```
"use client";
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { UserType, UserContextType } from "../types";

// Define the default user data
const defaultUser: UserType = {
  name: "",
  role: "guest",
  loggedIn: false,
  instagramLoggedIn: false,
};

// UserProvider component to manage the context value
interface UserProviderProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const UserContext = createContext<UserContextType | null>(null);

export default function UserProvider({ children }: UserProviderProps){
  const [user, setUser] = useState<UserType>(defaultUser);

  const login = (username: string, password: string) => {
    // ... Implement logic to authenticate the user
    // ... Set the user object with the authenticated data
    // Example: setUser({ ...user, loggedIn: true, name: username });
  };

  const logout = () => {
    // ... Implement logic to log out the user
    // ... Reset the user object to the default state
    setUser({ ...defaultUser });
  };

  const loginInstagram = (username: string, password: string) => {
    // ... Implement logic to authenticate the user on Instagram
    // ... Update the user object with the Instagram login status
  };

  const value = {
    user,
    login,
    logout,
    loginInstagram,
  };

  console.log(children)

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useUser(){
  const context = useContext(UserContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useUser must be used within a UserProvider');
  }
  return context;
}
```

Here is my app.tsx:

```
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import React, {useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { homeRoutes } from "./routes";
//import { adminRoutes, instagramRoutes, userRoutes, homeRoutes } from "./routes";

import { lightTheme, darkTheme } from "./theme";

import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
//import { UserProvider } from "./utils/user-state";
import UserProvider from "./utils/user-context";

export default function App(){
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(lightTheme);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateTheme = () => {
      const prefersDarkMode = window.matchMedia(
        "(prefers-color-scheme: dark)",
      ).matches;
      const newTheme = prefersDarkMode ? darkTheme : lightTheme;
      setTheme(newTheme);
    };

    window
      .matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)")
      .addEventListener("change", updateTheme);
    updateTheme();

    return () => {
      window
        .matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)")
        .removeEventListener("change", updateTheme);
    };
  }, []);

  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    //...adminRoutes,
    //...userRoutes,
    //...instagramRoutes,
    ...homeRoutes,
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserProvider>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <RouterProvider router={router} />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </UserProvider>
    </div>

  );
}
```

Here is my index:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './app';
//import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';


const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container!); 
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);


//reportWebVitals();
```

When I run my app, inside of my custom header component I call useUser(). The problem is that this results in an error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')". However, I am not sure what the issue is. I thought that maybe my components are not being passed as children of the UserProvider, or that the custom context is incorrect. I'm using react-dom@18.2.0, react-native@0.73.1, react-redux@9.0.4, react-router-dom@6.21.1, react-scripts@5.0.1, react@18.2.0.